# Using a vba-constant in Constant declaration

Tags: excel, vba, visio

### Update

I am an Idiot, the reason it didn't work was a `&` sign that got a bit to close to to `vbNewLine`. I didn't figure it out since I knew the `Chr(xx)` wouldn't work and immediately jumped to conclusions.
That the original was a multiline statement didn't help.  (Didn't cross check the code I wrote here)

### Original Post

So, I'm trying to declare a `Const` that holds a description for my class, the description will have a few line-breaks/new-lines (just a new paragraph)  in it.
The value of which will later be returned trough a Property Get Method.

I'm aware that you can't use function calls like `Chr(10)` (which is actually `vba.Chr(10)`) when setting the value of the Constant.

```
Private Const FOO As String = "Apple" & chr(10) & "Ale"
```

But apparently VBA-constants like `vbNewLine` (which is actually `vba.vbNewLine`) will not work either.

```
Private Const FOO As String = "Banana" & vbNewLine & "Beer"
```

I am aware that I could just write the text directly inside the `Property Get` Method, but I would like to have all the Info at the top.

An alternative I could think of would be implementing a small string-formatter that replaces a token with a vbNewLine, although I think this would be overkill.

```
Private Const FOO As String = "Cucumber {/CrLf} Cerveza"
```

So before I go ahead and implement the formatter I would like to ask the question:

Is there an easy way to declare a `vbNewLine` in the `Const` declaration/definition?

Comment: `Chr(10)`, fully qualified, is actually `VBA.Conversion.Chr(10)` - you can use the *Object Browser* to locate it ;-) I have no issues declaring a `Const` that uses anything in the `VBA.Constants` module to assign its value - `VBA.Constants.vbNewLine` is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Tim Williams, I'm not having any issues with using compile-time constant expressions to declare a constant's value.

EDIT:

> *the reason it didn't work was a `&` sign that got a bit too close to the `vbNewLine`.*

Now this makes more sense - the `&` character serves as the *string concatenation operator* when used as an operator (that is, `operand1 & operand2`, with spaces on either side). But it also serves as a *type hint* character that is legal to use on numeric literals, e.g. `42&` is a `Long` literal, whereas `42` would be an `Integer` literal. This is marginally useful, and forgetting to put that crucial space before the operator is a relatively common mistake.

Applied to a string constant like `vbNewLine`, the type hint causes a compile error: "type declaration character does not match declared data type"

Original answer below.

---

> *I'm trying to declare a Const that holds a description for my class*

Sounds like you're reinventing docstrings though. You can access module and member docstrings through the Object Browser by selecting *properties* from the context menu:

[image: class properties in the object browser]

The "Member Options" dialog that pops up lets you enter a description:

[image: "member options" dialog lets you enter a description]

This description will be visible in the Object Browser:

[image: custom description showing in the Object Browser's bottom pane]

IDE add-ins like [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (disclaimer: I manage this open-source VBIDE add-in project) can display this docstring in the project treeview:

[image: Rubberduck Code Explorer showing custom docstring in bottom pane]

...and everywhere it's referenced, too:

[image: Rubberduck toolbar showing custom docstring for selected 'Class1' identifier]

With `@ModuleDescription` annotations, custom module docstrings can be maintained from visible in-code comments (use `@Description` annotations for members).

Docstrings are a developer tool, they have little programmatic value, if any.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation! I do use Rubberduck quite a bit, without it my 6k-line VBA program wouldn't be manageable. In this case it's not gonna be a DocString. The class is used to run an inspection for certain criteria in the document... The class Implements an IInspection Interface and can be run trough a InspectionManager. Name and string would be there to tell the user what the test does exactly. Althought It probably would be better to have central module/file with the translations...

Comment: Consider having a `ListObject`/table on the worksheet, with a `Key` column, and then a column for each language you want to support, e.g. have the English description under a `en-US` column, French under e.g. `fr-CA`, and then you can have a function whose role is to lookup a resource key in that table and return the appropriate resource string given a (default?) locale.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with:

```
Private Const FOO As String = "Banana" & vbNewLine & "Beer"
```

What error are you getting with that?